# FULLTEXT query with scores/ranks in Postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, full-text-search

Im new to Postgres and I dont know how to translate this MySQL query to postgres:

```
SELECT pictures.id, MATCH (title, cached_tag_list) AGAINST ('phrase') AS score FROM pictures WHERE MATCH (title, cached_tag_list) AGAINST ('phrase') ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Postgres fulltext search is a little different from the MySQL fulltext search. It has a lot more options but can be a bit more difficult to get working the way you like it.

This document tells you how to rank your search results, but I strongly recommend you read the entire fulltext section from the manual to get an idea about what you can do with it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING

Basically, the equivalent of your query would be this:

```
SELECT pictures.id, ts_rank_cd(textsearch, 'phrase') AS score
FROM pictures
ORDER BY score DESC
```

As you can see, this uses `textsearch` which is something you will have to define yourself. For the short version, read: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-tables.html

The query is essentially very simple:

```
SELECT pictures.id, ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', pictures.title), 'phrase') AS score
FROM pictures
ORDER BY score DESC
```

But I would strongly recommend adding indexes aswell:

```
CREATE INDEX pictures_title ON pictures USING gin(to_tsvector('english', title));
```

Comment: Thanks Wolph. It looked pretty hard to understand at first, but finally I got it working.

Comment: What *is* `textsearch`? It isn't a column name at least. The documentation helpfully omits this detail.

Comment: @Timmmm: the documentation is perhaps a bit difficult to read in that aspect. It's a `ts_vector` which you can create like this: `SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'a fat  cat sat on a mat - it ate a fat rats');
`

Comment: Yeah, I can't work out how to get the `tsvector` *and* the rank, *and* sort by the rank in one query. Can you do a complete example that's something like `SELECT pictures.id, ts_rank_cd(tsv, query) AS score FROM pictures, to_tsquery('phase') query, (SELECT to_tsvector(pictures.title) AS tsv FROM pictures) .... ` Ok that is getting confusing. All I want to do is have the score as a column in my query so I can sort and filter by it. I keep getting errors about columns not existing or not being able to use things in the same level of something... Maybe I shold post this as a new question.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Also note that according to the documentation your index won't be used, because you didn't use `'english'` in the query.

Comment: @Timmmm: True that... I'll modify the answer to match :)

Comment: Final question (sorry!). Actually I made a new question because this is getting rather long: [Best way to use postgresql full text search with ranking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933805/best-way-to-use-postgresql-full-text-search-ranking).